# Android Navigation Component jump a few steps in graph at once

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I use navigation component, and I need to in certain situations navigate a few steps forward at once. For example `FragmentA` has direction to `FragmentB` and the later has direction to `FragmentC`. My goal is to in certain situations jump directly to `FragmentC` but have the normal navigation graph, so when user comes back from `FragmentC` he/she appears on `FragmentB` as if he appeared in `FragmentC` by one by one navigation.

I found that `NavDeepLinkBuilder` can solve my problem with the following:

```
            val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.my_graph)
                .addDestination(R.id.fragmentA_destination,
                .addDestination(R.id.fragmentB_destination)
                .setComponentName(MyActivity::class.java)
                .createPendingIntent()

            pendingIntent.send()
```

It actually does what I want but with 2 problems:

1. It finishes the calling activity, and I don't know if I can prevent it from finishing it.
2. This does not seem to be right at all, as `PendingIntent` is not designed to be used to navigate inside my own application, so what I do above seems to be a sort of hack.

So how else can I achieve the same result without using this `PendingIntent` mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `navigate()` multiple times, first to fragment B, then to fragment C. This is in fact precisely how deep links are internally handled by the Navigation Component.

Comment: But do you need to call it in the origin fragment or to validate this on each fragment oncreate?

Comment: @htafoya - like the answer says, you can just call `navigate()` multiple times back to back, all in the origin fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is valid, but just to expand a little bit on it, you will need to advance the steps from the origin fragment.

Keep in mind that if your navigation actions require parameters or navigation branches you'll have to manage those validations according to your app architecture.

if using **safeArgs** you can do:

```
with(findNavController()) {
    navigate(Fragment1Directions.actionTo2())
    navigate(Fragment2Directions.actionTo3(someParam))

    // use the correct path to maintain a correct back stack
    if(someValidation) {
        navigate(Fragment3Directions.actionTo4())
        navigate(Fragment4Directions.actionTo6())
    } else {
        navigate(Fragment3Directions.actionTo5())
        navigate(Fragment5Directions.actionTo6())
    }

    navigate(Fragment6Directions.actionTo7())
}
```